# AutoSSH for a robust tunnel

Tags: ssh, upstart, tunnel, autossh

I'm trying to start an ssh tunnel from A to B and have it run despite things like: period network/wifi drops on A and remote server reboot on B.  My ssh tunnel starts using upstart script on A with *event start on (net-device-up IFACE=eth0)*

I've found autossh which is supposed to handle these kinds of things, but had some trouble getting it to work.  The upstart executes:

```
autossh -M 0 -2qTN -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 2" -L 5678:somehost:5678 user@B
```

However when I log into B and kill -9 that tunnel session, autossh just exits with "Connection to B closed by remote host."  That's not what I expected autossh to do.

Any advice on how to set this up?  Any GUI service monitoring utilities out there that essentially display a green light if a service is up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a combination with screen will help. 
For auto reconnect you will need a key authentification too.

I created an alias:
alias sshtunnel='TERM=xterm ssh servername -a -x -t /opt/local/bin/screen -xRR -A -e^Zz -U -O -S tunnelToServer'
Screen ensures that you terminal session is alive.

Last step is creating a script which checks the host and starts the alias again:
$ while :; do while ! ping -c1 -t1 server >/dev/null; do sleep 10; done; sshtunnel; echo Connection to server dropped at $(date); sleep 10; done

That should survive all network drops. You can play around with the sleep times too.

If you call screen -ls you will find your screen session with the name "tunnelToServer".